# Possible to use PrimeVue with NativeScript-Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-vue, primevue

I am trying use the PrimeVue [project](https://primefaces.org/primevue), but being new to nativescript and javascript in general, I am either stumped or barking up the wrong tree.  I added it to my nativescript-vue project with

- npm install primeicons --save
- npm install primevue --save

And I see the source in my node_modules/primevue.  However, when I try to declare them in my app.js:

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue"; 
import Button from 'primevue/button';
import ToastService from 'primevue/toastservice';

Vue.use(ToastService);

Vue.component('Button', Button);
const  vn = new Vue({
  render: h => h('frame', [h(routes.home)])
}).$start();
```

and in my home.vue I include it as:

```
  <template>
    <Page class="page">
        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" class="full-height">
            <StackLayout class="container" alignItems="right">
                <Button class="p-button-raised p-button-rounded"  label="Submit"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

But it's not actually rendered.  In my IDE, I see a warning that

> "unresolved style class.   Inspection info: under construction"

Comment: I think Stack overflow needs a PrimeVue tag but I don't have permissions to create tags.  I removed your PrimeFaces tag as its not PF related.

Comment: I think you can't because you can't use Vuetify in Nativescript-Vue too. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6311

Comment: Do you know if there is a similar library that gives the data grid so I can display tabular data in a reactive way?

Comment: that has a lot more features than I need, but yea that looks like what I am looking for.  I am looking at www.ag-grid.com datagrid, but am struggling to get it to render.

Comment: @steven omg did you really upload real users to the internet xD with their email address too xD

Comment: @webfacer what are you talking about?

Comment: @steve hmmm there was a link which you provided, now it is gone and i cant find it. but i have the image ^^ with all of them to show you what you have done. but oki if it´s no more on the internet i am oki with it.